# What is the "user" in user == owner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner of rails and learning with the book "Beginning rails 4". I can't understand the "user == owner" part in the code below.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :body

  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_many :comments

  def owned_by?(owner)
    return false unless owner.is_a?(User)
    user == owner
  end
end
```

Where does the "user" come from? What is it? User is a model as I know of, what is the "user" then?

Comment: user actually means self.user

Comment: FWIW i think coding best practice should ALWAYS be to use `self.methodname` as it makes it clear to the reader that you're referencing a method rather than a local variable, which otherwise looks the same.

Comment: I would personally rewrite the contents of that `owned_by?` method to simply be `owner == self.user`.  If owner isn't even a User object then it will return false anyway: the first line is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a method call on your `Article` instance. Specifically, because your Article `belongs_to :user`, it's the User record that your Article belongs to.

For more details on association basics: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference